# Input field text is white on white in some apps on OnePlus One

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, oneplus-one, text-input, color

After upgrading to Android 6 on an unrooted OnePlus One, some apps (eg. Aqua Mail, aCalendar) have their input fields nearly white text on white background.

How can I change the color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing to another theme in settings -> themes did the trick

Comment: Please expand this answer by including some more details, like what steps do we need to change the theme, or whether it's on a single app, or whole system, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I have an un-rooted android oneplus one and I recently upgraded to 6.0.1
I did not see any such problem in my phone. You can try following and see if it works:

1. Try restarting the phone
2. Try selecting a dark theme
3. Make sure that your Cyanogen OS version is updated too (mine is 13.0)

Let me know if it works :)